# Getting the index of an element from an Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, frp, rx-android

I'm beginning to learn RxJava. I have an array of Views that I want to set an `OnClickListener` to each of them using `ViewObservable.clicks()`. The implementation of the `OnClickListener` will just call a method that depends on the position of the view in the array (e.g.: `populate(viewPositionInTheArray)`).

An imperative solution will be this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
    final int finalI = i;
    view[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            populate(finalI);
        }
    });
}
```

In order to do that using RxJava, I guess I'll need to do some stream chaining. However, I have no idea what functions I must use in an elegant, FRP way of doing it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: not sure I understand you question. If you are looking for the position of a view, I don't see how that relates to Rx?

Comment: your solution would not work, because the `i` is not final, and cannot be used in the onClick. You need a way to get the index from the view. Typically, putting it in the tag. `view[i].setTag(i)` then `.map(view -> (Integer) view.getTag()).map(this::populate)` or `.map(view -> populate((Integer) view.getTag()))` (this uses retrolambda for concision).

Comment: Sure it won't work, I just typed it directly here on SO to illustrate what I was thinking. Using tags are a good idea, but your answer suggests that I'll have to iterate through the array to set the tag anyway. I'm looking for a solution (not sure if possible, though) to avoid any iteration.

Comment: there is always `view.getParent().indexOfChild(view)`, but that gives you the position in the parent viewgroup, which can be de-correlated from the list you work on. If you have a list `list.indexOf` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my stab at it. I ussualy use range operator when I need to maintain index through observable change

```
 Observable.range(0,views.length)
               .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer integer) {
                views[index].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        populate(index);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
private void gotTheList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mViews.length; i++) {
        setClick(mViews[i], i);
    }
}

private void setClick(View item, int index) {
    ViewObservable.clicks(item)
            .subscribe(onClickEvent -> {
                populate(index);
            });
}

private void populate(int index) {
    // do something on mViews[index]
}
```